# Make Vim stop highlighting certain underscores in my Markdown as errors

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-markdown

I'm using Kramdown-flavored Markdown in several of my Jekyll websites. Vim highlights all the underscores in those documents as errors, coloring them (in my color scheme) with bright red backgrounds. For those who don't know, Jekyll Markdown pages begin with a Yaml document containing metadata before the main document starts. Thus, at the top of an example file I have something like this:

```
---
layout: v4_main
date: Fall 1999
permalink: /music/effects_of_music.htm
# etc for many more lines
```

where all the underscores have bright red backgrounds. Throughout the actual Markdown portion of the document I have similar issues related to Kramdown's extensions to Markdown.

Following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19137899/713735), I managed to fix most of the issues by creating `$HOME/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim` with this line:

```
:syn match markdownIgnore "\v\w_\w"
```

However, the fix is incomplete, and I don't understand why. My documents have a number of headings that look like this:

```
## General Effects of Music {#general_effects_of_music}
```

The part in the curly braces is Kramdown's way of setting the header's `id` when rendering to HTML. Despite my updated Vim syntax rule, the underscores in the `id` are still labeled as errors. Any idea why, or how I can silence those errors?

**NOTE:** I've tested my regex in a search (`/\v\w_\w`) and it matched everything I want it to match, so clearly the issue isn't a bug in my regex.

Comment: Ive used the liquid plugin (i think from tpope) for my jekyll sites with no issue.

Comment: @user938271: It gets rid of the error coloring, but it also changes the color of underscores to be the same as the background color, making underscores appear as spaces.

Comment: Really? Ive not noticed that...

Comment: It's possible that it could be some interaction involving my color scheme (`industry`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a way to suppress the error markings in the kramdown ids. So why not highlight them differently? Perhaps like this:

```
syn match kramdownId "{#[^}]*}"
syn cluster markdownInline add=kramdownId
highlight def link kramdownId Identifier
```

This highlights `{#...}` in light blue (in my color scheme).

Note: I have no full kramdown file to test if there are any side effects.

Comment: This answer fixes my problem as I described it, though I've updated the match regex to handle all Kramdown identifiers: `{[.:#][^}]*}`. Nonetheless, in further testing I found yet more issues with the Markdown highlighter, so I've switched to using a [plugin](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown) to highlight my Markdown.